# How to retrieve values after calculation?

Tags: java

I have a method to show the values of table that satisfy the condition: show all value in table tblFuel if `alarmType != 60` and nearest `alarmType == 60`, all of my code here:

```
public ArrayList<FuelData> BaoCaoDoXang(String accountID, String deviceID,
        String fromTime, String toTime, String timezone)
        throws DBException, SQLException {

    ArrayList<FuelData> list = new ArrayList<FuelData>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    DBConnection dbc = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    FuelData reportFuel;
    int alarmType = -1;//(1)initialize here*********************************************************1
    try {
        dbc = DBConnection.getDefaultConnection();
        long epf = ConvertToEpoch(fromTime + " 00:00:00", timezone);
        long epl = ConvertToEpoch(toTime + " 23:59:59", timezone);
        String sql = "SELECT * "
                + " FROM tblFuel F INNER JOIN tblDoXang DX "
                + " ON DX.thoiGian = F.timestamp "
                + " where (F.timestamp BETWEEN " + epf + " and " + epl
                + ") " + " and F.accountID = '" + accountID
                + "' and F.deviceID = '" + deviceID
                + "' and F.alarmType = '" + alarmType//expectation value(4)*************************4
                + "' order by F.timestamp asc";

        stmt = dbc.execute(sql);
        rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        double lastValue = 0;
        int temp = -1;
        while (rs.next()) {
            // double fuel = rs.getDouble("nhienLieu");
            temp = rs.getInt("alarmType");
            if(temp != 60)
                alarmType = temp;
            if(temp == 60 && alarmType != -1)//(2)alarmType value after calculation*****************2
            {
            double currentValue = rs.getDouble("fuelLevel");
            double changeValue = lastValue == 0 ? 0 : currentValue
                    - lastValue;
            lastValue = currentValue;
            reportFuel = new FuelData(rs.getString("accountID"),
                    rs.getString("deviceID"), rs.getInt("timestamp"),
                    rs.getDouble("latitude"), rs.getDouble("longitude"),
                    rs.getString("address"), currentValue,
                    rs.getDouble("odometerKM"), rs.getInt("status"),
                    changeValue,alarmType ,//(3)here************************************************3
                    rs.getDouble("nhienLieu"));
            list.add(reportFuel);
            /*
             * if(fuel > 0){ changeValue = fuel; }
             */
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqe) {
        throw new DBException("ReportByStatusCode", sqe);
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
        }
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
        }
        DBConnection.release(dbc);
    }
    return list;
}
```

I initialized my variable(alarmType) in (1) `int alarmType = -1;//(1)initialize here*********************************************************1`
 and then checked the given condition and calculated in (2) and got the satisfied value in (3). I expected to put value of alarmType in (3)

`double lastValue = 0;
        int temp = -1;
        while (rs.next()) {
            // double fuel = rs.getDouble("nhienLieu");
            temp = rs.getInt("alarmType");
            if(temp != 60)
                alarmType = temp;
            if(temp == 60 && alarmType != -1)//(2)alarmType value after calculation*****************2
            {
            double currentValue = rs.getDouble("fuelLevel");
            double changeValue = lastValue == 0 ? 0 : currentValue
                    - lastValue;
            lastValue = currentValue;
            reportFuel = new FuelData(rs.getString("accountID"),
                    rs.getString("deviceID"), rs.getInt("timestamp"),
                    rs.getDouble("latitude"), rs.getDouble("longitude"),
                    rs.getString("address"), currentValue,
                    rs.getDouble("odometerKM"), rs.getInt("status"),
                    changeValue,alarmType ,//(3)here************************************************3
                    rs.getDouble("nhienLieu"));
            list.add(reportFuel);
            /*
             * if(fuel > 0){ changeValue = fuel; }
             */
            }
        }`

to (4) and then execute the query

```
String sql = "SELECT * "
                    + " FROM tblFuel F INNER JOIN tblDoXang DX "
                    + " ON DX.thoiGian = F.timestamp "
                    + " where (F.timestamp BETWEEN " + epf + " and " + epl
                    + ") " + " and F.accountID = '" + accountID
                    + "' and F.deviceID = '" + deviceID
                    + "' and F.alarmType = '" + alarmType//expectation value(4)*************************4
                    + "' order by F.timestamp asc";
```

. I have checked and recognized that the value return in (3) is true, however it seemed that the value in (4)(alarmType) which got from (1)(alarmType = -1), but not from (3) so my code return the wrong result. So my question is: how to retrieve correctly value from (3) to put to (4)?(In the other word: how to get value of `alarmtype` in while loop to put in in SQL query?).(other way) It is very easy if I add one more column in my table to put the values that calculated in (3)(by writing a service in somewhere), but what I can do without of doing that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Consider posting [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with a simple explanation of what are you trying to do - it would probably get more traction!

Comment: The simple explanation is can I and how to come from (1) -> (2) -> (3) and finally (4). My code seem come from (1) -> (4) directly?

Comment: The fact that your question seems simple to understand and obvious to you - is great. Now all you have to do is make sure that the people you want to help you will think the same :) Good luck!

Comment: Define `alarmType` outside the loop and modify it inside the loop. So, as long as the loop goes on it uses the modified value.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
alarmType
loopingConstruct {
    sql String
    execute sql string to get result set (rs)
    loop through rs
    get alarm type value and set it to alarm type
    create FuelData object
    add FuelData to the list
}
```

Looping construct context holds the modified value of `alarmType` during its execution which will be used in `sql String`.

Assumption - Result set (`rs`)  returned contains only one row. If this is not the case then `alarmType` will have its value set to the value returned by the last row in the `rs`.